Is it ok to call both joinAll() then awaitAll() on a list of coroutine jobs to enure my Android viewmodel waits for all jobs to complete?
My current android application has a strange bug associated with running multiple kotlin coroutine jobs to call back end json apis.
initially I had the following code in an Android viewmodel:-
val jobs = mutableListOf<Deferred<Result<MyResult>>>()

jobs += doWorkOne()
jobs += doWorkTwo()
jobs += doWorkThree()
...
jobs += doWorkN()

  val completedJobs = jobs.awaitAll()

  val isFailuresExist = completedJobs.any { it.isFailure }

...

the majority of the the time all the required updates were actioned and my data reflected the applied changes.
however, intermittently one or more updates appeared to have been "missed", although I could see no logs showing api failures.
I had a feeling its because the viewmodel was not waiting for all jobs to complete and  being 'shut down' and cancelling the jobs when one or more jobs took "a long time" to complete.
as awaitAll() docs say this ...
Awaits for completion of given deferred values without blocking a thread and resumes normally with the list of values when all deferred computations are complete or resumes with the first thrown exception if any of computations complete exceptionally including cancellation.

therefore I added a call to joinAll() as follows:-
val jobs = mutableListOf<Deferred<Result<MyResult>>>()

jobs += doWorkOne()
jobs += doWorkTwo()
jobs += doWorkThree()
...
jobs += doWorkN()

jobs.joinAll() //ADDED THIS CALL

val completedJobs = jobs.awaitAll()

val isFailuresExist = completedJobs.any { it.isFailure }

...

with the call to joinAll() I have been unable to recreate the intermitent bug.
however it doesnt "feel right" to call both joinAll() and awaitAll()
is this an acceptable approach?
how else could I ensure my viewmodel waits for all the jobs complete?

It is fine to do jonAll before awaitAll, but in most cases this is the same as simply awaitAll. I suspect that some of your jobs crash, that causes the awaitAll to throw. If you don't do joinAll, the caller crashes earlier, if you do joinAll first, it will still crash, but a little later. Still, it doesn't feel like a proper solution, but rather a really ugly hack.
